# How do you change collation for one specific column with EF Core 7?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm trying to query a database using EF Core 7, and now realizing there are some columns with different collation settings and it is causing some querying errors/conflicts. How can I add code to the modelBuilder to fix this?

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" in the equal to operation.
> Invalid column name 'JdfTypeCode'.

I tried setting up the `modelBuilder` to use an explicit collate (`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`) but I still get the same conflict.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: [Column collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity#column-collation)

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping to be able to do this in the ModelBuilder in EF as opposed to in sql\sql server with t-sql. Thank you.